# python wx to show popup after main screen has been initialized

Tags: python, dialog, wxwidgets

I want to show a popup above my main screen like so:

```
|´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´|
|   I WANT TO BE SHOWN.|
|    |´´´´´´´´´´´´´|   |
|    |  I AM A     |   |
|    |  POPUP      |   |
|    |_____________|   |
|______________________|
```

The problem is that when I have the following code:

```
class A(a_frame_class):

   def __init__(self, parent):
       a_frame_class.__init__(self, parent)
       dialog = a_frame_class.dialog()
       if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            #do stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = wx.App(False)
frame = A(None)
frame.Show(True) #<-- Why is this not "proccing" ?
app.MainLoop()
```

It only shows the popup window, so the "parent" window isn't shown until dialog stops blocking. How do I work around this?
I have tried `threading`, `wx.CallLater`, `wx.CallAfter`, and putting it in a method `dialogmethod` and calling that. They all work the same, i.e it still blocks. I'm guessing im missing something fundamental here, because this usually works with other dialogs in other programs (albeit with slightly different structures)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That's because "parent" window shows after calling Show method. When you initialize frame, **init** is called and dialog is created. `frame.Show(true)` is called when **init** finishes executing, so when dialog is dismissed. Your code should look like that

```
class A(a_frame_class):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        a_frame_class.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Show()
        dialog = a_frame_class.dialog()
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            #do stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = A(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

If we add right use of calling superclass methods, Your code should look like that

```
class A(a_frame_class):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(A, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Show()
        dialog = super(A, self).dialog()
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            #do stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = A(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```